# JavaScript String.split() function returning an array with 20 empty strings

Tags: javascript, string, split

I am trying to make something similar to the way that jQuery uses strings to determine HTML elements. I tried using a split function to make it become a list of the different values but instead it returned an array with 20 empty strings.

```js
console.log('button#hello.something'.split(/.|#/))
```

And the result is:

```js
[
  '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
  '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
  '', '', '', '', '', '', ''     
]
```

Comment: You need to escape the `.` to make it literal. Or use `[.#]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` means any single charactar in regex, you need to skip it using a backslash:

```js
console.log('button#hello.something'.split(/\.|#/))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is wrong if you want to match exactly dots and sharps. You need to evade both like so `/\.|\#/`
Dots in regexp matches any character, so your split function effectively splits your string by any character.

Comment: `#` shouldn't need escaping ~ [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399078/283366)